# Javascript: adjacent Elements Product algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a basic javascript algorithm and i'm kinda stuck, here is the question:

> Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that
>   has the largest product and return that product.
>
> Example
>
> For inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3], the output should be
>   adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) = 21.
>
> 7 and 3 produce the largest product.

Here is my code, i can't find the problem but in the tests it says that it returns null:

```
    function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    var cb;
    for(var i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++){
      if(inputArray[i] !== inputArray[inputArray.length-1]){
        if(inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1] > cb){
          cb = inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1];
        }
      }
    }
  return cb;
  }
```

What is my problem and what i need to change?

Comment: Either the array is empty or at least one of the two `if` conditions are always preventing the assignment. Did you try stepping through the code while it's running so as to examine the values?

Comment: You update `cb` only when the first number is equal to the last number in the array. That condition is true for the last element, in which case you access `inputArray[inputArray.length]`, which isn't a valid index.

Comment: @llama I changed it, thank you i didn't notice that, but the function still returns null.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `if(inputArray[i] !== inputArray[inputArray.length-1])`?

Comment: @Xufox I tried to prevent the function from continuing  to do things when the loop is at its last item, I don't really know what it would do if it would get to the last item but i did it just in case.

Comment: Numbers are never `>` or `<` than `undefined` (which `cb` is `undefined`), so your if statement is always false

Comment: @WackThat Then compare indexes, not array values, or simply loop up to the index before the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you never initialized `cb`. So the comparison with `cb` is always invalid. Here is the correct version of your code -

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    var cb = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for(var i=0;i<inputArray.length-1;i++){
        if(inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1] > cb){
          cb = inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1];
        }
    }
  return cb;
}

console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 7]))
```

Comment: @Xufox fixed. The first `if` was rather problematic and unnecessary which I didn't notice, my bad.

Answer (score 7):

What you ultimately want to do is iterate through the array *excluding* the last member, and compare a product of each current item with its next adjacent member to that of the largest one found thus far.

You can use `.slice()` and `.reduce()` for this.

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(arr) {
  return arr.slice(0, -1)
            .reduce((max, n, i) => Math.max(max, n * arr[i + 1]), -Infinity)
}


console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]));
```

---

An alternate solution would be to create an array of products using `.map()` after doing the same `.slice()`, and pass that array's members to `Math.max`.

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(arr) {
  return Math.max(...arr.slice(0, -1).map((n, i) => n * arr[i + 1]))
}


console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce we can simplify the amount of code.

```js
var a = [3, 6, -2, -2, 7, 3].reduce(function(a, b, i, arr){
  if (b*arr[i-1] > a)
  {
      a = b*arr[i-1];
  }

  return a;
})

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `[3, -6]` yield `-18`? You default to the first array element as the starting value, but you should provide `-Infinity` as a starting value to `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to use pairs of elements - you can just run through it and keep store maximum product value, something like this:

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(items) {
    var product = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
        product = Math.max(product, items[i] * items[i + 1]);
    }
    return product;
}

console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]));
```

Comment: This answer does not work for negative numbers.
This test fails: input: [ -23, 4, -3, 8, -12] > expected outpur: -12 > output from code 0.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could iterate from index `1` to the end and use `i - 1` and `i` for adjacent elements. Then you could check if you are in iteration one and take the value or if the multiplication is greater then the old value, then assing the greater product.

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    var cb, i;
    for (i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (i === 1 || inputArray[i - 1] * inputArray[i] > cb) {
            cb = inputArray[i - 1] * inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return cb;
}

console.log(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

More generic solution:
This will work for every array with negatives and non negatives numbers.

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {

    int length = inputArray.Length;
    int max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++ ) {
        max = Math.Max(max, inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1]);
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Implementation of Kadane's algorithm Good Job!

Answer (score 0):

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(std::vector<int> inputArray) {
    int n=inputArray.size();
 int p=1;
 int maxp=inputArray[0]*inputArray[1];
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
       p=inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]; 
       if(p>maxp){
           maxp=p;
       }       
    }
    
    return maxp;
}
```

Comment: This is a very simple code in C++ with time complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will do that in Python:

```
 def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    max = inputArray[0]* inputArray[1]
    for i in range(0, len(inputArray)-1):
            if inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] > max :
                max = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1]
                i+1
            else:
                i+1
    return max
```

Or you can do it in one line like:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    return max([inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] for i in range(len(inputArray)-1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function largetProduct(inputArray) {
   let pairs=[];
     for(var i = 0;i<inputArray.length ;i+=2){
         pairs.push(inputArray.slice(i,i+2))
     }


    let products = pairs.map(v=> v[0]*v[1] || 1);
        return (Math.max.apply(0,products));
 }
```